# ZF not autoloading models and forms from module

Tags: zend-framework

I have come across a strange problem with Zend_Framework, I can not load forms or models from any module other than default.

I have the following line of code in my controller (in the user module)

```
$myAccountModel = new User_Model_MyAccount();
```

However all i get is the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'User_Model_MyAccount' not found in F:\My Webs\freedate\application\modules\user\controllers\MyAccountController.php on line 13
```

I have checked the files path and class name and all is correct, I have this project setup similar to other ZF projects I have done in the past, the only difference is that this is on a WAMP server rather than a LAMP server.

If I try to load a model or form from the default module it loads fine, these line of code produce no errors and the classes load fine.

```
$loginForm = new Form_Login();
$loginModel = new Model_Login();
```

If someone can shed some light as to what is going on here it would be most helpful as I have now hit a brick wall!!

I am using ZF 1.11.11 btw.

Many thanks

Garry

[EDIT]

This is definatly a probelm with ZF autoloader, if I add the following line the error goes away.

```
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/user/models/MyAccount.php');
```

In my application.ini i have

```
; modules
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
```

and in my bootstrap.php I have

```
/**  * Initialize autoloader  
 * @return Zend_Loader_Autoloader  
 */     
protected function _initAutoload() {    
    return Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); 
}

/**  * Initialize module autoloader  
 * @return Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader  
 */ 
protected function _initModuleAutoload() {
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'));

    return $modelLoader; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add an empty Module_Bootstrap to the specific module? Like so:

```
<?php

class User_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap 
{// nothing in here except you really want to do anything here ;)}
```

Once you do this, you can remove the `_initAutoload()` and `_initModuleAutoload()` methods from your bootstrap.  When you create a module bootstrap, the Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader is automatically created by default for that module.

See [The Module Resource Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module)

Comment: That was it, I forgot to add the bootstrap files to the modules. Thanks your a lifesaver.

Comment: I was able to remove the _initAutoload() from the bootstrap but not the _initModuleAutoload(), when I removed that the whole app fell over because it could not find my ACL file (Fatal error: Class 'Model_FreedateAcl' not found).

Comment: To prevent that, you should set an `appnamespace` in your application.ini file, and prefix all classes that are not part of a module with that, so it might be `Application_Model_FreedateAcl` instead of just `Model_FreedateAcl`.  Or you can set up a loader with no namespace like you did.